# Questions about the Negation of the statement

Tags: logic

statement: $\exists x\in R^n, \forall z \in R^n $ \ {$x$} : $F(x) > F(z)$

Can I say that negation of this statement is $\forall x \in R^n, \exists z \in R^n$ \ {$x$} : $F(z) \geq F(x)$ ?

Moreover, I want to ask general Qn. Can I say that negation of $(A \iff B)$ is $(A \land \lnot B) \lor(B \land \lnot A)$ ?

Comment: For the first one, the middle bit should be $\exists z \in R^n \setminus \{x\}$, of course (but I suspect that's a typo). Basically, the answer is yes! (in classical logic...)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $A\Longleftrightarrow B$ is equivalent to $(A\Rightarrow B)\wedge (B\Rightarrow A)$.
Moreover, $A\Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to $\neg A\vee B$. Now apply De Morgan's law.

Moreover, in view of quantified statements, $\neg \forall x [x\in R^2\Rightarrow F(z)\geq F(x)]$ is equivalent to $\exists x[\neg([x\in R^2\Rightarrow F(z)\geq F(x)])$, which amounts to $\exists x[x\in R^2\wedge F(z)<F(x)]$.